# wordpress wp_mail() function with jquery $.post()

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post

I'm building custom contact form on wordpress using jquery $.post() function.

```
$.post(tmpl_dir + '/bugreport.php',{ name:name, email:email, message:message }, function(data) {
                if ( data ) alert( 'thanks for answer' )
                else alert('error sending, please try again.');

            })
```

(tmlp_dir is theme directory path)

here is bugreport.php file:

```
<?php 
if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) &&isset($_POST['message']) ) {
    $name = $_POST['name']; $email = $_POST['email']; $message = $_POST['message'];
    $send_to = "mail@mail.com";
    $subject = "Question from " . $name;
    $success = wp_mail($send_to,$subject,$message);
            if ($succsess) return true
            else return false;
}
?>
```

I'm getting an error from wordpress that says: wp_mail() function not defined.
How can i let my php file use wp_mail() function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the wordpress ajax hook in order to get wordpress classes.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

I would recommend cleaning the code a bit and adding a Nonce check, but your code should look something like this:

js:

```
jQuery.post(
    MyAjax.ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'send_message',
        'name':'name', 
        'email':'email', 
        'message':'message'
    }, 
    function(response){
        alert('The server responded: ' + response);
    }
);
```

php:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_message', 'do_send_message' );

function do_send_message() {

  if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) &&isset($_POST['message']) ) {
    $name = $_POST['name']; $email = $_POST['email']; $message = $_POST['message'];
    $send_to = "mail@mail.com";
    $subject = "Question from " . $name;
    $success = wp_mail($send_to,$subject,$message);
            if ($succsess) return true
            else return false;
  }

}
```

To load your js file and vars add this to functions.php or your plugin.

```
$myvars = array( 
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', plugins_url( '/path/to/somefile.js', __FILE__ ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', $myvars );
```

Comment: Thanks, and what about just `include(wp-load.php)`?

Comment: yo need to declare it when you add your script, you can do so using something like this: wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

Comment: I have edited the answer to add instructions for the wp_enqueue_script

Comment: You used `wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', plugins_url( '/path/to/somefile.js', __FILE__ ) );` plugins_url function. My javascript files not in plugins folder.

Comment: It should be `get_template_directory_uri()` instead.